# React-Router v4.2.2 not working (I think I've done something wrong in the Route tag?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I'm using react-router v4.2.2 in my project, and am trying to create a set of cards that each link to other components. Right now I'm just testing that the router works, by routing each Card to one specific component called 'Project1'. This, however, is not working; I'm not seeing the div inside the Project1 component pop up. What am I doing wrong?? Shouldn't each Card link to the Project1 component?

Here is the code for the main container that holds the cards:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProjectCard from '../components/project_card.js';
import Project1 from '../components/project1.js';

class ProjectCards extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var projectCards = this.props.projects.map((project, i) => {
            return (
                <div key={i}>
                    <Link to={`/${project.title}`}>
                        <ProjectCard title={project.title} date={project.date} focus={project.focus}/>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div>{projectCards}</div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        projects: state.projects
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProjectCards);
```

Here is the code for the Routes container:

```
import React from 'react';
import Project1 from '../components/project1.js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class Routes extends React.Component{
    render() {
        var createRoutes = this.props.projects.map((project, i) => {
            return <Route key={i} exact path={`/${project.title}`} component={Project1}/>
        });
        return (
            <Switch>
                {createRoutes}
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        projects: state.projects
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Routes);
```

Here is the code for the index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './components/App.jsx';
import css from '../style/style.css';
import style from '../style/style.css';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and the code for Project1, which should display when a Card has been clicked:

```
import React from 'react';

const Project1 = () => {
    return (
        <div>hello there this is Project1</div>
    );
}

export default Project1;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you click on a link, you navigate to Project1, which has no Routes defined.  You basically destroy your Route when you lick on it because the Switch is in the same component as the Link.  The Switch statement needs to be moved to a 3rd component so that it still exists after clicking on a linking card.

Comment: i added a separate component where I placed the routes, and initially placed the component inside the projectCards component, but it didn't work. Then, I placed the component into my App.js, but it's still not working. I will edit the question to update the changes made to the code and will place the new component there. What am I doing wrong now??

Comment: Oh I figured it out! I wasn't using the withRouter function from react-router at the bottom of the routes container, where the connect function is! Now it's working. Thank you for your help though :D